# What is the efficient way to filter and copy files from Azure blob storage that contains million files using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: performance, filter, copy, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I want to copy files in a Container in an Azure blob storage which contains around 10,000,000 CSV or Zip files.

Filename format looks like "Energy_ReportName_Timestamp_VersionNumber.zip". The sample filename could be "Energy_Payment_20231209110007_0000000404988124.zip".
VersionNumber at the end of the filename doesn't have a regular pattern.

I want to filter **zip** files for a specific **ReportName** and **Date**, and copy those files to another container.

For example, files for "ReportName" = Payment; and Date = 20231209 (at any time on this date and any VersionNumber).

Since there are millions of files in the source container, I am looking for an approach that is fast to find the desired files and copy them to the sink container using Copy activity in Azur eData Factory.

Note that this is a requirement from the client to use Azure Data Factory. It is part of a pipeline. All files are located in the container and there is no subfolder or nested folder.

Please let me know if there is any idea.

Comment: Can't you filter the files you want by just cp \*Payment_20231209\*.zip /newdir/?

Comment: Are your files exist in a source container or nested folders of source container? I mean can you priovide the folder level of all files?

Comment: @SimonGoater This is a requirement from the client to use Azure Data Factory. It is part of a pipeline.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula All files are located in the container and there is no subfolder or nested folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **wild card file name in the copy activity source** as suggested by @[Simon Goater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20460267/simon-goater) in comments.

Go through the below demo:

These are the files in my input container named `inputdata`.

```
Energy_Payment_20231209110007_0000000404988124.zip
Source_Payment_20231209010215_0000000404982426.zip
Employee_Payment_20231209122424_00000004049171224.zip
Business_Cash_20231209101602_0000000404988124.zip
Fund_Payment_20231208161001_0000000404988124.zip
```

In copy activity of ADF pipeline, take binary source and binary target dataset. In the source dataset, give the path till the container name.

[image]

Similarly, give the path till the target container in the target binary dataset.

[image]

Now, give the source dataset to copy activity source and give the wild card file name `*Payment_20231209*.zip` like below.

[image]

Give the target dataset to the copy activity sink and Debug the pipeline. You can see the required files will get copied to the target location like  below.

[image]