# Recommend pattern in ADF when you want to have filter out files already read?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have 1700 files and each day new ones are added. I have a file where I have all the files names that I already have read listed.

I iterate over the files in the source and I iterate over the file names in the file list that contains the names. Each file in the source that is not in the file list is being processed. After process I update the file with the new filename added.

It is an expensive run.
[image]

I dont think it is expensive because of the vCore hours (i think) but because of the numbers of activity runs.

Do you have any suggestion on how to reduce the cost?
I need to only process files that have not been processed and I sometimes need to process files that have been processed before - for data quality purpose.

Pipeline flow:
[image]

The DeltaFileList returns the delta of the filenames in the lookup file and the acutal files. Almost all the activity runs is about appending to variables.

And here is the structure of the files:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your pipeline flow and what are the activities that you are using? and what is your source here? how are your files located in the folder? are they nested or in a single folder?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula just updated with some pictures and text

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below pipeline design to reduce the number of activities.

But for this you need to two pipelines, first you need a manual execution of first pipeline run and after that you need to build a second pipeline.

First copy all of your current files in the source to destination manually using a copy activity in a pipeline and store the pipeline end time in a csv file `date.csv` like below. The date should be in `UTC` timezone.

[image]

Now, build the second pipeline. You need to use this pipeline to copy the daily files of yours using schedule trigger on that time.

In this pipeline, It will fetch the last pipeline run time from the above file and use that in the Get meta data activity `LastModified StartTime` to get the files list which are new after the last pipeline run.

Use this list as per your requirement and at the end of the pipeline, use a **copy activity to update the above file with latest pipeline run date**, so that in next pipeline run, the new files will be processed.

Schedule this second pipeline everyday as your files will be loaded daily.

take a look up activity to the above file like below.

[image]

**My sample file structure:**

```
inputdata
    folder1
        folder1sample1.csv
        folder1sample2.csv
    folder3
        folder2sample1.csv
        folder2sample2.csv
```

Create another dataset and use wild card place holder as per your folder level. Here my folder level is only 1.

[image]

Take this in the Get meta data activity and give the below expression in the **StartTime**.

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.curr_date)
```

[image]

After the Get meta data activity, build your activities in the pipeline. The Get meta data activity child items will be the files list which are not loaded. Use this as per your requirement.

At the end of the pipeline, take the copy activity. Here, to update the date file, use a temporary csv file with dummy data like below.

[image]

Give this as copy activity source and the `date.csv` file as sink. Add an additional column to update the `curr_date` column.

[image]

For sample second run, I have added new files `folder1sample3.csv` and `folder2sample3.csv` in the directories. You can see it is giving only the new files when executed second time.

[image]

Check this similar [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651560/18836744) for reference.